# Flutter firebase push notification in ios

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I am trying to setup ios push notification using firebase and flutter. When I send a test notification from firebase console with my emulator's device token, it comes to vs code editor's console since I have a print in `onMessage`. When I send the app in testflight, I get an email from apple that

```
ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment' entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,.....
```

But I did setup push notification, I am confused, if it was not done correctly then how I was able to see the notification in emulator?

I have also enabled push notification in `signing and capabilities`
[image]

I connected my iphone and run the project in device, I didn't see any notification pop up, but I got it like this

[image]

Anyone can help me where did I do wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Emulators can't receive push notifications. Please, check Apple's guidelines and limitations.

Comment: Yes it can catch notification but cannot show. I was able to execute onMessage function by sending some test notification from firebase

Comment: yes in foreground but not in background. Do you have the APN certs everything on your account?

Comment: Yes I think. Or may be I missed something :(

Comment: Ok solved it, everything was good, problem is, I didn't ask for notification permission from the code, so it didn't send notification in background